# The type of the SQL statement could not be determinated

Tags: c#, firebird2.5, firebird-embedded

When I'm trying to execute following query

```
<!-- language: sql -->

    CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE GENERATOR GEN_STUDENT_ID;

    SET TERM ^ ;
    CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER STUDENT_BI FOR STUDENT
    ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
    AS
    BEGIN
       IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN
       NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_STUDENT_ID,1);
    END^

    SET TERM ; ^
```

I'm getting the error "The type of the SQL statement could not be determinated"

This script is running by c# code

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded;
csb.Database = "mydb.fdb";
csb.UserID = "SYSDBA";
csb.Password = "masterkey";

string conString = csb.ToString();
FbConnection.CreateDatabase(conString);

FbScript script = new FbScript("DB_GEN.sql");
script.Parse();

using (FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(conString))
{
    conn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection opened");

    FbBatchExecution fbe = new FbBatchExecution(conn);

    foreach (string cmd in script.Results) {
        fbe.SqlStatements.Add(cmd);
    }

    try {
        fbe.Execute();
    }catch(Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    conn.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

I'm using Firebird Embedded v2.5.1 and FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient v2.7.0.0

Comment: do you get error when running script not in c#?

Comment: Determinated?  I'd try a different SQL client.

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer from another site. It appears there was need to replace this line

```
FbScript script = new FbScript("DB_GEN.sql");
```

by this

```
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"C:\TEMP\DB_GEN.sql");
FbScript script = new FbScript(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

Script was run correctly!